# Table of contents hierarchy frontmatter

Tags: table-of-contents, front-matter

I'd like to add a different hierarchy to my table of contents.
Currently it looks like this.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xesearch} %word count
\usepackage[margin=.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subcaption} %subfigure
\usepackage{caption} %subfigure
\usepackage{changepage} %indentsforquotes
\usepackage{lipsum} %indents for quotes
\graphicspath{{./Dissertation/}}
\usepackage{float}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % numebrs pages
\doublespacing %double spaced lines


%TO USE GREEK

\usepackage{textgreek} 
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifXeTeX
\usepackage{fontspec}
\else
\usepackage{luatextra}
\fi
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\setmainfont{cmun}[
Extension=.otf,UprightFont=*rm,ItalicFont=*ti,
BoldFont=*bx,BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]
\setsansfont{cmun}[
Extension=.otf,UprightFont=*ss,ItalicFont=*si,
BoldFont=*sx,BoldItalicFont=*so,
]
\setmonofont{cmun}[
Extension=.otf,UprightFont=*btl,ItalicFont=*bto,
BoldFont=*tb,BoldItalicFont=*tx,
]

%END OF GREEK


%bib
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


\begin{document}

\section{Abstract}

enter an abstract? 

\pagebreak

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

lalala

\section{Conclusion}

hi hi 

%references list
\pagebreak

\section{Ancient Sources and References}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Res Gestae
\end{enumerate}

insert references here
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}




\end{document}
```

but i would like to have my abstract not be numbered the same as the sections. instead, I would like it to be labeled i, ii, iii, ix, etc.
i would like to add an acknowledgements section and other things that would be in this prior section.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your MWE (except that it is anything but minimal as it only needs to include code that is relevant to your problem).

```
% secumprob.tex  SE 650381

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{comment}   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  PW

\begin{comment}
  
\usepackage{setspace}
%%%%\usepackage{xesearch} %word count
\usepackage[margin=.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subcaption} %subfigure
\usepackage{caption} %subfigure
\usepackage{changepage} %indentsforquotes
\usepackage{lipsum} %indents for quotes
\graphicspath{{./Dissertation/}}
\usepackage{float}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % numebrs pages
\doublespacing %double spaced lines

%TO USE GREEK

\usepackage{textgreek} 
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifXeTeX
\usepackage{fontspec}
\else
\usepackage{luatextra}
\fi
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\setmainfont{cmun}[
Extension=.otf,UprightFont=*rm,ItalicFont=*ti,
BoldFont=*bx,BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]
\setsansfont{cmun}[
Extension=.otf,UprightFont=*ss,ItalicFont=*si,
BoldFont=*sx,BoldItalicFont=*so,
]
\setmonofont{cmun}[
Extension=.otf,UprightFont=*btl,ItalicFont=*bto,
BoldFont=*tb,BoldItalicFont=*tx,
]

%END OF GREEK

\end{comment}

%bib
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


%title page
%old 
\title{Sales of sail: The economy of Roman sail production}
\author{Leah Tavasi \\ University of Oxford \\ MSc Archaeology}
\date{Submitted: August 31 2022}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage} 
%\input{title page}   %%%% you don't provide that
\thispagestyle{empty} %does not number first page

\end{titlepage}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\roman{section}}  %% roman numbers for sections

\section{Abstract}

enter an abstract? 

or a section called acknowlegements or other sections

\pagebreak

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{section}{0} %%% start section numbers again 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} %%% with arabic numbers


\section{Introduction}

lalala

\section{Conclusion}

hi hi 

%references list
\pagebreak

\section{Ancient Sources and References}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Res Gestae
\end{enumerate}

insert references here
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

After the `\begin{document}` above you can see code for changing the numeration of sections.